# How can I build a smart Oracle of my own for a smart contract?

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, remix

I need my smart contract to access data from some source. I want to build a smart Oracle in order to achieve this.

Comment: This may help to build your own oracle https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/how-do-oracle-services-work-under-the-hood

Answer (score 2):

I think what you meant by "some source" is calling external APIs, like in order to query a database on the Internet.

Due to the deterministic nature of the EVM you need a service like [Oracalize](http://www.oraclize.it/).

The Answers to following questions might help you as well : 
 [how can ethereum contract get data from a website](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-get-data-from-a-website), 
 [Why can't contracts make API calls](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/301/why-cant-contracts-make-api-calls)