# How can an Ethereum contract read data from excel

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Is there a possibility to read excel from smart contract? If yes how? Do I need some relay or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read data from an external source inside a Solidity contract, but depending on your needs you could do one of the following.

1- Utilize a service such a [Oraclize](http://www.oraclize.it/) that allows your contract to obtain data from an external source. You could build an API and have your contract query it through Oraclize.

2- You could process the excel file client-side, say in JavaScript, and send a transaction to your contract with the processed data as input.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to deploy the smart contract and let it access the sheet, I think you may first need to keep it in a remotely accessible place.

So basically you can store the spreadsheet and open an api end point access it. (This can be done by many server side implementing languages/ [Google sheet api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/) also would be ideal and easy - at least for testing ).

Now the problems is reduced to smart contract access an api. You may use a service like [Oraclize](http://oraclize.it/) for that. As oraclize says,

> Smart contracts live like in a walled garden, they cannot fetch
>   external data on their own. Oraclize is here to help. Orcalize act as
>   a data carrier, a reliable connection between Web APIs and your Dapp.

Refer [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/24805/how-can-i-build-a-smart-oracle-of-my-own-for-a-smart-contract/24810#24810) and [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-get-data-from-a-website) questions.

[Question here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28748/how-can-an-ethereum-contract-read-data-from-excel) would give a good idea on how this works.