# Is there a way to communicate with big files stored in a database from ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

For example, if my smart contract holds very basic detail of a patient and I want to access his / her medical report stored in a database (mongoDB) .

Comment: Do you want your contract to access the database and get data to use inside its business logic?

Comment: Yes @ Luiz Soares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you are going to need a service like Oraclizeit. You may find a rough explanation about it here: [How Oraclize and API call works](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/how-oraclize-and-api-call-works)

And if you use Oraclizeit and it returns to your contract a big amount of data, you may explode your gas amount and won´t be able to execute your function. You should take that in count.

You can´t make a direct connection between your contract and mongoDB. Contracts must be atomic.