# Some info of contract when price of something reach some level

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-deployment

I'm total newbie. Let's assume I want to create a contract that sell BTC when price reach 20.000$ for example, how can I do that? How smart contract check the price? How many times? I don't understand how smart contract can see the price of BTC and how many times check it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### In theory

- Imagine some service, which imports data from the "world outside" to
  blockchain. This is called Oracle and you can read about it
  [here](https://blog.oraclize.it/understanding-oracles-99055c9c9f7b).
- Now, we can find (or [build our own](https://www.smartcontract.com/features)!) Oracle which will constantly
  monitor Bitcoin price.
- When the desired price is reached your smart contract will create an
  [event](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events), which will be recognised outside the blockchain and the
  further actions will be made.

---

In addition, you might want to read:
[Watching Solidity Events](https://medium.com/@theMadKing/watching-solidity-events-the-right-way-d3d0a30bdc4d) (more practice, less theory).

Comment: Thank you very much Roman. So instead of an Oracle can I call an API from an Exchange (for example) or I MUST get data from an Oracle?

Comment: @rod what API are you referencing to? In blockchains we call such services Oracles.

Comment: Ok thank you. But where Oracle Is run? It run directly inside blockchain or where? Thank you very much

Comment: @rod I think [How do oracle services work under the hood](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/how-do-oracle-services-work-under-the-hood) is the best short answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you Roman. You are very helpful. In some way, I permit  a specified Oracle to send data to my contract, and then the contract check this data. Is this correct? I don't understand HOW an oracle is linked with a contract... I see that smartcontract.com has a chainlink system.

Comment: @rod don't worry, not many do. The interaction between Oraclize and an Ethereum smart contract is asynchronous. Any request for data is composed of two steps:  1) a transaction executing a function of a smart contract is sent by a user. The function contains a special instruction which manifest to Oraclize, who is constantly monitoring the Ethereum blockchain for such instruction, a request for data.  2) according to the parameters of such request, Oraclize will fetch or compute a result, build, sign and broadcast the transaction carrying the result.