# How to use smtp protocol in solidity smart contract via chainlink Oracle

Tags: solidity, python, smart-contract-wallets, brownie

i had developed a external adapter that make a http get request to cryptocompare api
and get latest eth-usd price for me.

```
from bridge import Bridge


class Adapter:
    base_url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price'
    from_params = ['base', 'from', 'coin']
    to_params = ['quote', 'to', 'market']

    def __init__(self, input):
        self.id = input.get('id', '1')
        self.request_data = input.get('data')
        if self.validate_request_data():
            self.bridge = Bridge()
            self.set_params()
            self.create_request()
        else:
            self.result_error('No data provided')

    def validate_request_data(self):
        if self.request_data is None:
            return False
        if self.request_data == {}:
            return False
        return True

    def set_params(self):
        for param in self.from_params:
            self.from_param = self.request_data.get(param)
            if self.from_param is not None:
                break
        for param in self.to_params:
            self.to_param = self.request_data.get(param)
            if self.to_param is not None:
                break

    def create_request(self):
        try:
            params = {
                'fsym': self.from_param,
                'tsyms': self.to_param,
            }
            response = self.bridge.request(self.base_url, params)
            data = response.json()
            self.result = data[self.to_param]
            data['result'] = self.result
            self.result_success(data)
        except Exception as e:
            self.result_error(e)
        finally:
            self.bridge.close()

    def result_success(self, data):
        self.result = {
            'jobRunID': self.id,
            'data': data,
            'result': self.result,
            'statusCode': 200,
        }

    def result_error(self, error):
        self.result = {
            'jobRunID': self.id,
            'status': 'errored',
            'error': f'There was an error: {error}',
            'statusCode': 500,
        }
```

i was successful in getting eth-usd price.
Here is the question that  can i use smtp protocol in smart contract?

smtp mail sending code

```
# the first step is always the same: import all necessary components:
import smtplib
from socket import gaierror

# now you can play with your code. Let’s define the SMTP server separately here:
port = 2525 
smtp_server = "smtp.mailtrap.io"
login = "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g" # paste your login generated by Mailtrap
password = "1a2b3c4d5e6f7g" # paste your password generated by Mailtrap

# specify the sender’s and receiver’s email addresses
sender = "from@example.com"
receiver = "mailtrap@example.com"

# type your message: use two newlines (\n) to separate the subject from the message body, and use 'f' to  automatically insert variables in the text
message = f"""\
Subject: Hi Mailtrap
To: {receiver}
From: {sender}

This is my first message with Python."""

try:
    #send your message with credentials specified above
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.login(login, password)
        server.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)

    # tell the script to report if your message was sent or which errors need to be fixed 
    print('Sent')
except (gaierror, ConnectionRefusedError):
    print('Failed to connect to the server. Bad connection settings?')
except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
    print('Failed to connect to the server. Wrong user/password?')
except smtplib.SMTPException as e:
    print('SMTP error occurred: ' + str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use external APIs on a blockchain.

More information in this answer: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/47778/620

Comment: can we do that via chainlink oracle ?

Comment: i am following this https://hackernoon.com/access-external-data-in-solidity-a-how-to-guide-jh193zio