# Smart Contracts and BigchainDB

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

How can I access data stored in blockchain database like BigchainDB using a smart contract in Ethereum?

Comment: A smart contract cannot interact with out of chain resources. To achieve that you have to use an oracle or similar. Read this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85178/what-is-a-blockchain-oracle.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael Can you point me to appropiate resources because I have no idea where to start.I mean I understood we need to make use of Oracle service but I'm searching for some code snippets that does this ETH contracts and bigchainDB integration.I'm currently working on developing a DApp using BigchainDB as the storage layer so that I can use the DApp for query purposes as well. I know how to integrate smart contract and ipfs(as the storage) but If I use ipfs I may not be able to design a query service using the Dapp. BigchainDB gives us that query facility.

Comment: It is not that complicated. You can start from here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/how-do-oracle-services-work-under-the-hood.